# Why np.corrcoef is not working as expected with two vectors of dimension two?

Tags: python, numpy, pearson-correlation

I am trying to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient between two vectors in 2-dimensions using `np.corrcoef`. When the dimension of the vectors is **different than two**, they work fine, see for example:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 3)
y = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 3)
print(x, y)
print(np.corrcoef(x,y))
```

Output:

```py
[-6.59840638 -1.81100446  5.6158669 ] [ 6.7200348  -7.0373677  -2.11395157]
[[ 1.         -0.53299763]
 [-0.53299763  1.        ]]
```

However, when the dimension is **exactly two**, the correlation is wrong with the only values `1` or `-1`:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 2)
y = np.random.uniform(-10, 10, 2)
print(x, y)
print(np.corrcoef(x,y))
```

Output 1:

```py
[-2.61268708  8.32602293] [6.42020314 3.43806504]
[[ 1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.]]
```

Output 2:

```py
[ 5.04249697 -3.6599369 ] [6.12936665 3.15827974]
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

Output 3:

```py
[7.33503682 7.7145613 ] [-9.54304108  7.43840944]
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

**Question:** What's happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Why is _the correlation is wrong_?

Comment: @Luke The correlation should be a float number between -1 and 1, it can't be -1 if the vectors are not opposite.

Comment: If the correlation between two variables is `-1` and `1`  it means they correlate perfectly, but in opposite directions

Comment: But this is not possible in this case, where the vectors are random and not opposite (in the example: [-2.61268708  8.32602293] [6.42020314 3.43806504]).

Comment: What do you think will be the correlation in that case?

Comment: @Luke Maybe I did not understand properly the Pearson correlation for vectors. I thought it would be some result similar to the dot product normalized but instead I think you can only calculate it if you have several random vectors and you can calculate means and variances.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple misunderstandings leading to your confusion:

*I'll use row major order as numpy "Each row of x represents a variable, and each column a single observation of all those variables."*

- The Pearson correlation coefficient describes the linear relationship between 2 variables. If you only have 1 value per variable , you can always create a linear relationship between the 2. With the normalization, you'll always get 1 or -1.
- A covariance or correlation matrix is usually calculated amongst the components of a random vector X=(X1,....,Xn).T . When you say you want the correlation between 2 vectors, it is unclear whether you want the cross-correlation between X an Y in which case you need [np.correlate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html).